# How to make an ANTLR rule "greedy"?

Tags: .net, parsing, grammar, antlr4, context-free-grammar

I recently started using ANTLR to generate a simple parser for interpolated strings. Some input string examples follow (one per line):

`Hello {User.Name}!`
`Welcome on Planet {GetPlanetName(" A stupid string param :-} ")}`
`Plain String without an interpolated expression`
`String with escaped {{ brackets }}`

The grammer to decide whether something is a string (plainString) or an expression (expressionString) is as follows:

```
grammar T;

patternString:                  (plainString | expressionString)+
                                ;

plainString:                    (CBO_ESCAPESEQUENCE | CBC_ESCAPESEQUENCE | PLAINSTRINGLITERAL)+
                                ;

expressionString:               CBO expression CBC | CURLYBRACKETS_EMPTY
                                ;

expression:                     expressionSegment+
                                ;

expressionSegment:              ~('"' | '\'' | '{' | '(' | '[' | '}' | ')' | ']' | CBO_ESCAPESEQUENCE | CBC_ESCAPESEQUENCE)+
                                | '(' expressionSegment+ ')' | '(' WS ')' | '()'
                                | '[' expressionSegment+ ']' | '[' WS ']' | '[]'
                                | '{' expressionSegment+ '}' | CURLYBRACKETS_EMPTY
                                | stringLiteral
                                | charLiteral
                                ;

stringLiteral:                  '"' (~('"') | '\\"')+ '"'
                                | '""'
                                ;

charLiteral:                    '\'' (~('\'') | '\\\'')+ '\''
                                ;

fragment WS:                    (' ' | '\r' | '\n' | '\t')+;

PLAINSTRINGLITERAL:             ~('{' | '}');
CURLYBRACKETS_EMPTY:            (CBO WS CBC | CBO CBC);
CBO:                            '{';
CBC:                            '}';

fragment CBO_ESCAPESEQUENCE:    '{{';
fragment CBC_ESCAPESEQUENCE:    '}}';
```

This is working very well except for some strings like the following:

{{{new[]{1, 2, 3, 4}}}}

Which gives me following AST

```
PatternString                                 => '{{{new[]{1, 2, 3, 4}}}}'
    ExpressionString                          => '{{{new[]{1, 2, 3, 4}}}}'
        Expression                            => '{{new[]{1, 2, 3, 4}}}'
            ExpressionSegment                 => '{{new[]{1, 2, 3, 4}}}'
                ExpressionSegment             => '{new[]{1, 2, 3, 4}}'
                    ExpressionSegment         => 'new[]'
                    ExpressionSegment         => '{1, 2, 3, 4}'
                        ExpressionSegment     => '1, 2, 3, 4'
```

Whereas I would expect (and want) the following AST:

```
PatternString                                 => '{{{new[]{1, 2, 3, 4}}}}'
    PlainString                               => '{{'
    ExpressionString                          => '{new[]{1, 2, 3, 4}}'
        Expression                            => 'new[]{1, 2, 3, 4}'
            ExpressionSegment                 => 'new[]'
            ExpressionSegment                 => '{1, 2, 3, 4}'
                ExpressionSegment             => '1, 2, 3, 4'
    PlainString                               => '}}'
```

Meaning, **`plainString` should be more greedy** and take as much escaped brackets as possible. How can I fix this in the above grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issues are due to the explicit definition of the rule for open and closing curly braces, but then referencing them in some of the parser rules as the string literal. By modifying the expression segment rule to only reference lexer rules, the issue seems to be resolved.
Please try out this grammar and see if your issue is fixed

```
expressionString:               CBO expression CBC | CURLYBRACKETS_EMPTY
                                ;

expression:                     expressionSegment+
                                ;

expressionSegment:
                                  L_PAREN expressionSegment+ R_PAREN
                                | L_BRACKET expressionSegment+ R_BRACKET
                                | CBO expressionSegment+ CBC
                                | L_PAREN WS R_PAREN
                                | L_BRACKET WS R_BRACKET
                                | L_PAREN R_PAREN
                                | L_BRACKET R_BRACKET
                                | CURLYBRACKETS_EMPTY
                                | stringLiteral
                                | charLiteral
                                | ~(DOUBLE_QUOTE | SINGLE_QUOTE | CBC | CBO | L_PAREN | L_BRACKET | R_PAREN | R_BRACKET)+
                                ;

stringLiteral:                  '"' (~('"') | '\\"')+ '"'
                                | '""'
                                ;

charLiteral:                    '\'' (~('\'') | '\\\'')+ '\''
                                ;

WS:                    (' ' | '\r' | '\n' | '\t')+;

PLAINSTRINGLITERAL:             ~('{' | '}');
CURLYBRACKETS_EMPTY:            (CBO WS CBC | CBO CBC);
CBO:                            '{';
CBC:                            '}';
L_PAREN: '(';
R_PAREN: ')';
L_BRACKET: '[';
R_BRACKET: ']';
SINGLE_QUOTE: '\'';
DOUBLE_QUOTE: '"';
```

As you can see, the parse tree seems to reflect what you are looking for

[image]

Comment: After a quick check, it seems to be working perfectly! Will run my unit tests tomorrow and let you know the results!